# How to construct signature list as parameter to invoke contract

Tags: smart-contracts, tezos-client, parameter

I write a contract and deployed it to babylonnet, address: KT1BcH97ZQas6zKMJBtNdmU4iBvyi2ihpsx8, the entry point is withdraw, parameter is amount, signatures, toAddr, txId(string). I use smartpy explorer to pack parameter,  but the explorer doesn't support list of signatures.
[image]

So I use tezos-client to invoke contarct, and I format a parameter by myself, but it doesn't work. My invoke command is:

```
tezos-client transfer 0 from alice to KT1BcH97ZQas6zKMJBtNdmU4iBvyi2ihpsx8 --entrypoint "withdraw" --arg '(Pair (Pair (Pair (Pair 1200000 (edsigtt9FQZSbtLvLx8UVZA1RJ29R7V9WUmmoSBjCcww1Y1pg3aXqWjspCFRc9kJ1MocXV7sMeULWtJuD8XLszQCk4J5FWC5ykh,edsigtpzq77tPRMeK1n9kdUiTroMfvnmGBXiQNib5cpRnAi4tiUReVydHQskB3q4hLvkaxpDYqP7ecUXzc2dR1sAvvYDbMG1idL)) "tz1WfxXzNgcsMrQBV6YHChmyQgNVvfo44ihi") "123123123")'
```

So what should I do to pack correct invoking parameter? Where is the description document about how to construct parameter?

After I modified command, there is a new error:
[image]

Comment: Has someone show me the golang code example about how to construct this operation and inject it to node?

Comment: I found the correct parameter format: ```pair (pair (pair 1200000 "edsigtt9FQZSbtLvLx8UVZA1RJ29R7V9WUmmoSBjCcww1Y1pg3aXqWjspCFRc9kJ1MocXV7sMeULWtJuD8XLszQCk4J5FWC5ykh" "edsigtpzq77tPRMeK1n9kdUiTroMfvnmGBXiQNib5cpRnAi4tiUReVydHQskB3q4hLvkaxpDYqP7ecUXzc2dR1sAvvYDbMG1idL") "tz1WfxXzNgcsMrQBV6YHChmyQgNVvfo44ihi") "123123123"```. But I got another error : ```Invalid argument passed to contract KT1TPBnfP...xrSxUuskS9.
Contract has no entrypoint named withdraw```. I have tried entry point name ```withdraw``` and ```Withdraw```. And I am sure that my contract entry point name is ```withdraw```.

Comment: You are calling a different contract, your question is about contract KT1BcH but the error is about contract  KT1TPB ...

Answer (score 2):

The format you use for lists is wrong.

You can look at the Michelson / Storage tabs in tests on SmartPy.io.

Lists constants in Michelson are of the form `{1; 2; 3}`.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the explicit call to the “—entrypoint” argument. The tezos node will figure it out by itself based on type checking of the “—args”